# jQuery Mobile - change view on radio button events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use JQM radio buttons to toggle between two views (all vs filtered list). I am trying to attach a script to the `changed` event that will switch the view. When the new page is loaded, I want the appropriate radio button to be highlighted to reflect the current view.

In the example below, I get seemingly erratic behavior (though of course it is deterministic; I just don't understand the behavior). I have two pages that are identical, except in two regards:

- In the two pages, the radio button with the `checked` element set is
  different.
- In the two pages, the body content (below the radio
  buttons) differs.

When the page below is loaded, `All Trips` is appropriately highlighted. If I click the `My Trips` button, the page changes: the other radio button is highlighted, and the body changes. But when I click the `All Trips` button on the second page, the body changes, and the radio button changes briefly, but then goes back to the `My Trips` state.

If I start from the second page, then the analogous behavior occurs.

```
<div data-role="page" data-cache="never" id="mainpage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="trippick">
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-all-trips" value="all" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-all-trips">All Trips</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-my-trips" value="mine" />
            <label for="radio-choice-my-trips">My Trips</label>
        </fieldset>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(":radio[name='radio-choice']").change(function () {
                    var selection=$(this).val();
                    if (selection == "mine") {
                        $.mobile.changePage("opt2.html");
                    } else {
                        $.mobile.changePage("opt1.html");
                    }
                });
        </script>

        <p>[All trips shown here.]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why use two different html pages, just change the content below the radio buttons for the same page dynamically, that is have only one opt.html in which just the content of <p> tag changes on radio selection appropriately.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VdQZ8/

Comment: Thanks, I will go this direction (show/hide via jQuery). I was frustrated by my lack of understanding and wanted to get to the bottom of it.